# how to force apache to crash?

Tags: php, windows, apache, crash, windows-error-reporting

I want to test something when apache crashes. The thing I want to test involves Windows asking me if it wants to send an error report. Any way to make Apache crash and ask me to send an error report on it?

Comment: `I want windows to display send error report`. Can you provide more details about what do you exactly wannt to do?

Comment: I want apache to crash in a way, where windows will give me a box saying to send the error report to Microsoft

Comment: I got an idea. Attach a debugger to Apache and overwrite some of the memory(Code Segment memory). That should segfault it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Advanced Process Termination](http://www.pendriveapps.com/advanced-process-termination-kill-running-processes/), especially its `crash` options, those might do what you want (display the send error report message box), although I haven't tested it. It's worth a shot though.

Comment: The force crashes don't seem to work on Windows7, but still a neat tool.

Comment: @IVlad Getting a 404 on the link posted.

Comment: @zengr I updated the link, however the app seems to be abandonware.

Answer (score 3):

Just kill the apache instance running.

**In windows:** go to taskmanager>kill the process

**In linux:** pkill processname

Comment: -1: Killing the process is not the same as causing an exception or simulating a crash.

Comment: A kill will simulate a machine crash. If not then I am curious to know, what is the difference? I am sure, the app mentioned in the accepted answer does the same thing internally.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the earlier idea that you should crash it using windows.

The basic of the apache is that for each connection request, it "fork" a new process. Since Windows don't have a built in "fork" functionality, it has to create a new process each request. As such, it can be glitchy especially if there are multiple processes running.

For me, everytime I "restart" apache on Windows while maintaining a connection, I get an "Illegal Operation" from Apache's process. Not sure that can be reproduced 100% of the time, but it does occur to me from time to time when I restart.

Answer (score 0):

[Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112950/alex) provides a possible [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284913/force-crash-an-application/4285080#4285080):

[Microsoft Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28VS.90%29.aspx) [...] can do fault injection (Low Resource Simulation) that makes various API calls fail, at configurable rates. [...]